# Install ubuntu on MacBook Pro 9.2

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Macbook pro 9.2 with OSX Yosemite 10.10.2. I have been running around and I can just not figure it out. Can someone please give me a tutorial or explain how I can install it relatively easily ?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Utopic, https://bmccarthy.net/2014/07/23/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbook-pro-91/

Answer (score -1):

I am using a MacBook too, and for me, the best practice is to use VirtualBox, a virtulisation software, free to obtain from http://www.virtualbox.org. Works great.

For instance, just click on the new VirtualBox button, and follow the guideline.

After that, mount Ubuntu's ISO files into VirtualBox. VirtualBox will boot into the installer. Install it as the way you would do on normal OS installation.

Another way is to use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). rEFIt is a boot menu and maintenance toolkit for EFI-based machines like the Intel Macs.

Comment: do you have a whats app name i cant get the virtual box to set up correctly wondering if you can walk me through it.

Comment: do i need to install something on the virtual box?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Matt: Please kindly refer to [this VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm). Questions could be asked here so that other people may found this useful.

Comment: David: Thank you! I've add further clarifications for the question.